# Macros support inside IntelliJ idea

Tags: scala, macros

I am reading this tutorial on scala macro code generation

http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/2016/12/01/scalameta-code-generation-tutorial

Based on this I wrote my macro class

```
class Foo extends StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any) : Any = meta {
     val q"..$mods class $tName (..$params) extends $template" = defn
     q"""
     ..$mods class $tName(..$params) {
     def sayMyName() : String = "Hello"
     }
     """
  }
}
```

Now I decorated my classes with the new attribute

```
package com.abhi
object Models {
  @Foo case class Bar(...)
  @Foo case class Baz(...)
}
```

If I write the following two lines

```
val x = Bar("test")
println(x.sayMyName())
```

and then compile using sbt `sbt macros/compile root/compile` and `sbt run` the code runs fine and I see that Hello is printed.

However the same code does not compile inside of intelliJ idea. (Ultimate 2016.3.3)

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: usually when debugging macros (scalameta or old macros), I use a lot of println statements to ensure that my code is actually being run.

If it is not, check your compiler settings to ensure the scalameta compiler plugin is actually active

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found that the code compiles and works fine from sbt but only from IntelliJ the method sayMyName is not visible. So I guess IntelliJ is not working properly when Macros are written.

Comment: Apparently there is an intellij plugin for scalameta. That could help

Comment: there is only a scala plugin (which I have already installed). I did not find any specific plugin for scalameta.